# Is it possible to get a UK visa gift card while in the US?

Tags: united-kingdom, europe

Is it possible to get a UK visa gift card while in the US? For instance, is there a place to purchase a UK visa gift card while still residing in the states and get it sent to me before leaving?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in fact I used this method for my travels to the UK. You can get one [from Travelex](https://buy.travelex.com/us/Purchase?product=94b39dc8-b7c4-4240-838d-df7a3c3e3b88&type=CashPassport&amount=700.00&event=Purchase&Currency=GBP), and you can even get it on the spot in some of their locations.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have to register a UK address? Or any address for these?  I can't seem to find that detail out.

Comment: @nateritter I registered my US address.

Comment: Thanks for all your help! This is amazing. I didn't know about this before.  Can you still buy products online with it?  What if I wanted to change the address to one in the UK?  Is that possible?

Comment: @nateritter I used it in places where chip and pin card is required, since the US cards don't have this feature. Haven't tried online purchases.

Comment: Ok. I'd love to know this if you have any way of finding out.  I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: And any way to move the address to the UK one once we're there?

Comment: You can call travelex and ask